# Rails Validation on has_many attribute

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a `Company`, `User` and `Department` model. There are multiple different companies, each of which `has_many` departments.

A `User` can belong to multiple `Departments` through a `UserDepartments` join table.

In my form for a `User`, I use:

```
<%= f.collection_check_boxes :department_ids, @user.company.departments.all, :id, :name %>
```

What is the best practice for validating that a malicious user did not use Curl etc to post a department_id that does not belong to the user's company?

I am currently using the following on the join table itself, but am wondering if there is a better accepted practice?

```
class UserDepartment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :department

  validate :check_company_matches

  private
    def check_company_matches 
      unless user.company_id == department.company_id
        errors.add(:user, "This department does not match the user's company.")
      end
    end
end
```

As a separate note, if a user does submit a malicious id, rails shows an exception page rather than the usual form rendering page with the errors object; why is that?

Another minor point of inelegance is that when you submit the User form with say 5 different departments checked, this validation will create 5 SQL queries. Presumably this can be done with one query if the User model itself did the validation. Naturally data integrity is my primary concern though.

Thanks.

Comment: It's probably not a good idea to add validation in join table model. Can you post the code of department model and user model?

Comment: @kasperite this is just an example however: Department simply `belongs_to :company` and User `belongs_to :company` and `has_many :user_departments` , `has_many :departments, through: :user_departments`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The thing that would stop a malicious user from curl'ing to your server is the csrf_token, so Rails is taking care of that one for you. That's probably the error that you're seeing.

I would keep business logic like validation on the Thing that it's validating. The join table is not the Thing itself; in fact, it has no Thing.

So by moving the validation to the User, you keep the logic in one place and avoid the extra sql.

```
def ensure_departments_in_company
  company_department_ids = company.departments.pluck(:id)
  unless deparment_ids.map { |id| id.in?(company_department_ids) }.all?
    errors.add(:user, "This department does not match the user's company.")
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks, the curl example was indeed incorrect. However if I go to 'inspect element' in e.g. Safari on one of the checkboxes, and change the value to a different number, then without that validation Rails will set the user's department to one that may not belong to the user's company.
I have tested your code and it works, thank you. I added the error to the `:departments` symbol instead though.